# listing contents of a jar file

Tags: java, jar

package soundcliptest;

```
// development environment(NetBeans 8.0)
//
// NetBeansProjects
//     SoundClipTest
//         Source Packages
//             resources
//                ding.wav
//             soundcliptest
//                SoundClipTest.java
//

// unZipped jar file
//
// SoundClipTest
//    META-INF
//    resourses
//        ding.wav
//    soudcliptest
//        SoundClipTest.class
//
```

I'm still learning how to use this tool, folks.  I can't seem to get the imports where they belong.

I need to know how to look into the jar file from the code.  The File methods can't  crack it.  There must be some way of finding the contents of a resource 'directory'. What I want to do is make a menu of the sound files under /resources/. I can make it work in the development environment,, but not from the jar file. Maybe some 'zip' methods? But I haven't found them.  Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

public class SoundClipTest extends JFrame {

    JTextPane myPane;
    String title;
    String showIt;

    public SoundClipTest() {

        // get something to write on
        this.myPane = new JTextPane();
        this.myPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 100));
        this.myPane.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));

        try {
            // Open an audio input stream.
            URL dingUrl = getClass().getResource("/resources/ding.wav");

            // show the path we got
            String path = dingUrl.getPath();

            //trim 'ding.wav' from file path to get a directory path
            String dirPath = path.substring(0, path.length()-"ding.wav".length());

            // now get a Url for the dir from getResource and show THAT path
            URL dirUrl = getClass().getResource("/resources/");
            String urlPath = dirUrl.getPath();

            // the dirUrl path is just like the trimmed 'ding' file path
            // so use  urlPath to get a file object for the directory
            try {
                File f = new File(urlPath);  //works fine in dev environment
                String filePath = f.getPath();  // but not from jar file
                title = f.list()[0]; // from jar, null pointer exception here

                // whan things go right (HA HA) we display this
                showIt = ("                >>>>> IT WORKED!! <<<<<!" 
                        + "\n path to file:        "+ path 
                        + "\n path to dir:        " + dirPath 
                        + "\n path from URL: " +  urlPath  
                        + "\n path from file:  "+ filePath + "\n " + title);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // you get this on display when executing the jar file
                showIt = ("          PHOOEY"
                        + "\n the ding  " + path 
                        + "\n trimmed path " + dirPath 
                        + "\n the URL path " + urlPath 
                        + "\n could not create a File object from path");

                 // the stack trace shows up only if you run from the terminal
               e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // We get a nice little 'ding', anyway
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(dingUrl);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(ais);
            clip.start();

            //but nuttin else good -  show the disapointing results
            myPane.setText(showIt);

        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("Ouch!!! Damn, that hurt!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SoundClipTest me = new SoundClipTest();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sound Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(me.myPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... Is there someplace I can find an explanation of how ti use this tool? Or do I just keep on experimenting.  Guess I can figure it out on my own if I have to.

Answer (score 0):

OK, not a full answer but since that part is not very well documented (Oracle's page on it is obsolete), here is how to use a ZIP FileSystem over a jar file:

```
final Path pathToJar = Paths.get(...).toRealPath();
final String jarURL = "jar:file:" + pathToJar;
final Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();

final FileSystem jarfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create(jarURL), env);

final Path rootPath = jarfs.getPath("/resources");
```

Then you can use `Files.newDirectoryStream()` over `rootPath` to get a list of files inside a "directory" within the jar. If you want to list recursively, use `Files.walkFileTree()` and write your own `FileVisitor` (most of the time, extending `SimpleFileVisitor` is enough).

**NOTE**: a `FileSystem` implements `Closeable`; you should ensure to `.close()` it once you're done with it. And so does a `DirectoryStream` for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

**Caveat Emptor**

This is assuming that you have not fiddled with classloaders, this will work with the `URLClassLoader` but is an implementation detail of that class, not part of the public API.

If you load a classpath directory resource then you will get a line for each resource in that directory.

Lets assume you have this structure:

```
/resources
    /test1.txt
    /test2.txt
```

If we do the following:

```
try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources"))) {
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
test1.txt
test2.txt
```

So you can use this to return a list of names of files:

```
List<String> readClassPath(final String root) {
    final List<String> resources = new LinkedList<>();
    try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream(root))) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            final String line = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            resources.add(root + "/" + line);
        }
    }
    return resources;
}
```

This returns:

```
[/resources/test1.txt, /resources/test2.txt]
```